# ngMessages validation in AngularJS doesn't clean the error message in CSS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, material-design, angular-material, ng-messages

Do you know why I keep having the red color underline error even when there is no error and validation passed fine??

[image]

I have my own directive to match both password and I'm using Angular material.

WORKING CODE HERE::::::::::::::

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gPrMRM

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gPrMRM

Angular app and js:

```
angular.module('MyApp', ['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages'])

.controller('AppCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.project = {
        description: 'Nuclear Missile Defense System',
        rate: 500
    };
})
.directive('validPasswordC', function () {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
            ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function (viewValue, $scope) {
                var noMatch = viewValue != scope.projectForm.password.$viewValue;
                scope.projectForm.password.$error = {};
                ctrl.$setValidity('noMatch', !noMatch);
                console.log("scope.projectForm.password.$error: ");
                console.dir(scope.projectForm.password.$error);
            })
        }
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="AppCtrl" layout="column" ng-cloak="" class="inputdemoErrors" ng-app="MyApp">
    <md-content layout-padding="">
        <form name="projectForm">
            <md-input-container class="md-block">
                <label>Client Email</label>
                <input required="" type="email" name="clientEmail" ng-model="project.clientEmail" minlength="10" maxlength="100" ng-pattern="/^.+@.+\..+$/">
                <div ng-messages="projectForm.clientEmail.$error" role="alert">
                    <div ng-message-exp="['required', 'minlength', 'maxlength', 'pattern']">
                        Your email must be between 10 and 100 characters long and look like an e-mail address.
                    </div>
                </div>
            </md-input-container>

            <md-input-container class="md-block">
                <label for="password">Password</label>
                <input type="password" id="password" name="password" ng-model="formData.password" ng-minlength="8" required />

                <div ng-messages="projectForm.password.$error" ng-show="projectForm.password.$touched || projectForm.$submitted">
                    <div ng-message="required">required.</div>
                    <div ng-message="minlength">Passwords must be between 8 and 20 characters.</div>
                </div>
            </md-input-container>
            <md-input-container class="md-block">
                <label for="password_c">Confirm Password</label>
                <input type="password" id="password_c" name="password_c" ng-model="formData.password_c" valid-password-c required />
                <div ng-messages="projectForm.password_c.$error" ng-show="projectForm.password_c.$touched || projectForm.$submitted">
                    <div ng-message="required">Please confirm your password.</div>
                    <div ng-message="noMatch">Passwords do not match.</div>
                </div>
                <br /><br /><br />
                <pre>projectForm.password.$error = {{ projectForm.password.$error | json }}</pre>
                <pre>projectForm.password.$touched = {{ projectForm.password.$touched | json }}</pre>
                <br />
                <pre>projectForm.password_c.$error = {{ projectForm.password_c.$error | json }}</pre>
                <pre>projectForm.password_c.$touched = {{ projectForm.password_c.$touched | json }}</pre>
            </md-input-container>
        </form>
    </md-content>
</div>
```

WORKING CODE HERE::::::::::::::

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gPrMRM

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gPrMRM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because you have a $parser that is not returning a value. You should change your directive to use the validators pipeline instead of the parsers.

```
<input type="password" id="password_c" name="password_c" required
       ng-model="formData.password_c"
       valid-password-c="{{formData.password}}" />


ctrl.$validators.noMatch = function (value) {

    // Return true if either of the passwords have not been provided yet
    if (!attrs.validPasswordC || !value) {
        return true;
    }

    return value === attrs.validPasswordC;
}
```

Updated to pass original password as attribute

Comment: thanks! I'll do that... just wondering, what do you mean by "decouple your directive from your form."?

Comment: Right now, that directive would not be very reusable since you are referencing your projectForm.password model directly in the directive. You could alternately pass that value as an attribute for the directive and use that attribute when checking that hte passwords match instead of grabing the $viewValue from your model like that.

Comment: I understand what you mean, but How can I pass the value as an attribute for the directive? I'm new in directives

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to return the viewValue from the $parser function:

```
    ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function (viewValue, $scope) {
                var noMatch = viewValue != scope.projectForm.password.$viewValue;
                scope.projectForm.password.$error = {};
                ctrl.$setValidity('noMatch', !noMatch);
                console.log("scope.projectForm.password.$error: ");
                console.dir(scope.projectForm.password.$error); 
                return viewValue;
            })
```

Here's a working [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EPKNYW?editors=101)